# Java ListIterator Robustness

Tags: java, listiterator, robustness

I hava a simple `LinkedList` in Java, that has, say, 10 elements. At that state, I get an ordinary `ListIterator`, say .listIterator(3). If I then insert/remove other elements into the list, without touching the element on which I have the `ListIterator` (nor the iterator), will the `ListIterator` still be valid?

Comment: This will depend on, and be documented in, your implementation of `List`. In the general case, no.

Comment: I was hoping I could avoid implementing a linkedlist myself that has such behavior... I guess I will have to do so, sadly..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you modify a `java.util.LinkedList` outside of the `ListIterator`'s own methods then the iterator is adulterated and will throw `ConcurrentModificationException` if you try to use it again.

This is covered in the [javadoc for linked list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html):

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator
>   methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any
>   time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the
>   Iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a
>   ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent
>   modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than
>   risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time
>   in the future.

Comment: s/will/may/ (does not apply to `CopyOnWriteArrayList`)

Comment: Ye I just tried it myself, after I posted the question I realized I could simply test it, wasn't thinking about it throwing an exception.. Thanks anyway :)